# Microsoft Flow always run in context of user who published it

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, microsoft-flow

I am new to MS Flow, I am looking for your guidance so that I can start using it in better way.

I created MS Flow for one list and it runs when item as added, the flow updates one field in list.

Now issue is  : **when ever anybody add the item, the Flow updates that field but last modified user shows my name instead of user who has added that workflow.**

I want flow to run in context of user who added the item (like designer workflow does) so that **modified by** column has correct value

Please guide me if I am doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 4):

If your flow is running on an automated trigger then it will always run in the context of an owner of flow (Who created the flow).

So that is who shows up in Modified By field in your SharePoint list.

However the manually triggered flows, like the ones that start with a button in a PowerApp runs in the context of the user who presses the button.

**Possible workarounds:**

1. You could use a manual trigger for your Flow and it would update the way you want.
2. But if you want an automated flow then the only way to do this is to use a REST call to manually set the Modified By field after making the update. Here's an article on how to do it.

   [Modifying Modified By and Modified time with Microsoft Flow](http://johnliu.net/blog/2019/2/flowninja-hack-78-modifying-modified-by-and-modified-time-with-microsoft-flow).

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be possible to change accepted user connections to run a flow in context of the starting user instead of the creators connection.

You should read this article. Maybe this will work for you: https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/advanced-button-sharing/

Answer (score 2):

This request has been taken up , at least mentioned in the community forum so that Microsoft goes ahead and gives a solution for this .

Something similar to this has been raised and since you are facing a similar problem please vote or leave your comments here .

[https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Flow-Ideas/Allow-the-creator-of-a-sharepoint-List-item-to-be-the-creator-of/idi-p/96906][1]

It is the default behavior that “Created By” or “Modified By” in SharePoint list will be the flow creator but not user who triggers the flow.

You can still try "**Manage Run-Only Users**" but that only appears on manual triggers, such as Flow Button, SharePoint “For a selected item” and “For a selected file”.

Please see the following blog for more details:

https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/advanced-button-sharing/