# PowerAutomate - what permissions are used when running a flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, power-automate, powerapps-forms

I have a PowerApp with a button that triggers a flow. The flow adds an item to a SharePoint list.

Current permissions for users:
PowerApp - read
Flow - run-only
SharePoint list - edit

**My goal**
Users should be able to add and edit items in the list by triggering a flow from PowerApps.
They **should not** be able to see items created by other users.

I cannot use the "edit only the items created by user" setting on the list, as there are other users who need to be able to have edit access to all items.

**additional question**:
What permissions PowerAutomate Flow uses when running - the credentials from connector, or the credentials of the user, who run the flow? Is it possible to implement an "impersonation step"?

Comment: Refer to [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/269396/microsoft-flow-always-run-in-context-of-user-who-published-it)

Answer (score 2):

1. For first part you need to assign custom permissions to the item created (becareful with scaling, if you list will have >50K items it is not an option as you will hit SP Limits)
2. PowerAutomate will use identity you set up in the connector.

Comment: Thank you!
In my case when users open the app they are asked to allow connections to SharePoint and Office 365, then the app uses their credentials when adding new items to the list etc. Is there a way to make sure the app and more importantly flows run from the app are run with the owners (my) credentials? Its is a stand alone power app